# Observable stream, whose values are enriched from other, "one-shot" Observables

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a helper function that makes an API call and returns an array of `items`. Each of these items represents an entity, let's say a `User`.

Each user has a `category_id` property which is null by default. I would like to populate this property, for each user, from the result of another helper function that takes a user ID and returns an Observable of the Category object, from which I can extract the ID, to be used as `category_id` attribute of the user.

I've reached the following (pseudo) code (TypeScript syntax, but the question is applicable to Observable operators in general):

```
this.backend
    .request(
      'v1/users',
    )
    .pipe(
      map(items => {
        items.forEach(user => {
          this.categories.getName(user['id']).subscribe(category => {
            user['category_id'] = category['id'];
          });
        });
        return items;
      })
    )
```

Naturally, this doesn't work because it's mixing Observable operators with Array functions (forEach).

Answer (score 2):

You should not subcribe to an observable within a pipe. It's an anti-pattern.
Use your higher observable and mergeMap with combineLatest to get what your want:

```
this.backend
.request(
  'v1/users',
)
.pipe(
  mergeMap(items => {
    const requestUserWithCatArray = items.map(user => this.categories.getName(user['id']).pipe(
        map(category => {
             user['category_id'] = category['id'];
             return user;
        })
    ));
    return combineLatest(requestUserWithCatArray);
  })
);
```

It will return an array of users with their category.

Comment: You could use `forkJoin` instead of `combineLatest` to run the requests in parallel and not in sequence (presuming `this.categories.getName(user['id'])` completes).

Comment: forkJoin might be of better use in this case, yes.